# baxter.sh can not run for baxter simulator

Tags: simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I have installed the baxter simulator in my PC, but when I run the baxter.sh, it comes this message:
[image: image description]

I can not find some useful solution about this from google, thank you for help!

$ env | grep ROS

ROS_DISTRO=indigo

ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/yin/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros

ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/yin/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243885/baxter.sh-can-not-run-for-baxter-simulator/) by [yin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25699/yin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2016-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue is definitely that you are using `zsh` as your default shell. On [line 178](https://github.com/RethinkRobotics/baxter/blob/master/baxter.sh#L178) of the `baxter.sh` script, you can see they start a new shell using the `SHELL` environment variable with the argument `--rcfile`.  `zsh` doesn't have this argument available, and that is what triggers your error. If you want to use this script as-is, you can't use zsh. If you want zsh and this script, then you'll need to debug the script a bit

Just FYI, I personally never use the `baxter.sh` script when working with Baxter. All the script really does is ensure that you have set the ROS_MASTER_URI and the ROS_HOSTNAME/ROS_IP environment variables correctly. I manage these variables with my own scripts and avoid their script primarily because

- their script requires you to actually edit it to update some of the variables -- this is not convenient for me. I work with multiple Baxter's that use the same workspace. I don't like needing to constantly change the script.
- I don't like how they automatically change my prompt to be such a long string. I have a highly customized prompt, and don't want it to be messed with.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25699/yin/) on 2016-09-16**:
That's it. Thank you very much for kind help, I get it.